# nested foreach for time table getting foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

Tags: laravel, foreach, html-table

I want to make a weekly schedule time table using `foreach` with given variable, but I got an error saying **foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given**, I don't know where I was wrong, can anyone help me?

Here is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $WEEK_DAYS = [
            '1' => 'Senin',
            '2' => 'Selasa',
            '3' => 'Rabu',
            '4' => 'Kamis',
            '5' => 'Jumat',
            '6' => 'Sabtu',
        ];
        $time = [
            '1' => '09.00 - 10.00',
            '2' => '10.00 -11.00',
            '3' => '11.00 - 12.00',
            '4' => '12.00 - 13.00',
            '5' => '13.00 - 14.00',
            '6' => '14.00 - 15.00',
        ];
        
        $weekDays     = $WEEK_DAYS;
       

        return view('kesiswaan.jadwal_index', compact('weekDays', 'time'));
    }
```

and here is my view

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th width="125">Time</th>
        @foreach($time as $time)
        <th>{{ $time }}</th>
        @endforeach
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($weekDays as $day)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$day}}
            </td>
            @foreach($time as $time)
            <td>
                Hari : {{$day}} <br>
                Jam : {{$time}}
            </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm guessing `@foreach($time as $time)` is probably not a good idea, you should make that _second_ `$time` something else.

Answer (score 0):

The **time** variable is a **string**, so when you try to use it as an argument to the **foreach()** function, you get an error. You can fix this by changing the **time variable to an array** like below:

```
@foreach($time as $key => $value)
<th>{{ $value }}</th>
@endforeach
```